# Display one row in the view from ListView

Tags: android, listview

I had a ListView created programmatically, and I need to display only **ONE** visible row between the red borders not multiple items, and scroll to get the others.

[image]

This my function

```
    public void fillFormules(List<Category> objectsTextToShow)

{
    LinearLayout layoutItemDetail = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.middle);
    LinearLayout relativeLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.titles);

   LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    for (int j = 0; j <objectsTextToShow.size() ; j++) {

        TextView textCat = new TextView(getActivity());
        textCat.setText(Check.Languages(objectsTextToShow.get(j).getName(), LANGUAGE_ID));
        textCat.setTextSize(28);
        textCat.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f));
        textCat.setTextColor(colorUtils.TITLE);
        textCat.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        relativeLayout.addView(textCat);
        textCat.setBackgroundColor(colorUtils.backgroundColor);
        LinearLayout parentLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        parentLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (float) 1.0));
        parentLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        ListView listView = new ListView(getActivity());
        for (int i = 0; i <objectsTextToShow.get(j).getItems().size() ; i++) {
            items.add(objectsTextToShow.get(j).getItems().get(i));

        }

        listView.setAdapter(new ScrollAdapter(getActivity(), items));

        parentLayout.addView(listView);
        layoutItemDetail.addView(parentLayout);

        listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            }
        });
    }
```

I use this xml to inflate the view, even I give match parent fot the weight and the height but it doesn't work :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

This what I must have in the end but I don't know how to do it :/

[image]

Comment: you need to make adjustment in row layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a fix height to your `Linearlayout` used to display every item of the list. And put also the same height to your `listView`

```
LinearLayout parentLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        parentLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, yourHeight, (float) 1.0));
```

And in your LinearLayout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="yourHeight"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: Thank's, I add this line to the Adapter         `rowView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(parent.getWidth(), parent.getHeight()));`
, it gives me what I need but the last listview had incorrect value of height and width. but just another question , **yourHeight** it depends to the screen so it can't be fixed, right ?

Comment: That's the same idea that I told you (there are lots of ways of doing the same thing).... anyway.. you can pass a fix value in  dp for the height or even get the height pixels of the device and set a a fraction of the screen height as height to the linear layout.